An Alien Lands - where?
This is a question of general knowledge though if anyone gets it without investigative effort I would be mightily impressed. All you need is in the text and you will then require some intuitive, deductive and reasoned research. A couple of hints may steer you in the right direction. Good luck.
An alien lands and takes a look around...
This is a hamlet in England. A pretty little place with a few dwellings.
My archive tells me that a future transport pioneer was born here. No blue plaque but there is one marking the location of his last days 300 earth-miles away on the other side of this country.
It seems there had been an earthling settlement an earth-mile or so east of here about 5500 years ago. Time has moved on and there is what looks like a fortress, but isn’t, atop a hill where recently it is reported that a famous stolen car was dumped.
Going a little north-east to discover more I enter the main town. Earthlings found valuable materials in the ground here and created shafts and tunnels to extract it. A statue of one of these men, sculpted in bronze, stands in commemoration. A short walk from the statue I find an artfully decorated house in which they view moving pictures – seems to have been in honour of their ruler.
Not staying long. I need to transport elsewhere. See you in a while.
Can you find the answers to these questions?

What is the name of the hamlet?
Who was the transport pioneer?
Where was he when he died and you find a blue plaque?
What is the name of the ancient settlement?
What car was stolen and why was it famous?
What is the name of the town?
What is name of the sculptor?
What is the name of the moving picture house?

Disclosure: I have my own web page with the puzzle.
https://analienlands.com/landing-001/
Hint 1

 There are few parts of England which are separated by a distance of 300 miles and the 'other side' implies west to east.

Expansion of hint 1

 England is at its widest between Cornwall in the south-west and Essex in the east

Hint 2

 What forms of transport pioneering began in England?

Answer to hint 2

 Railways - steam locomotion


@bobble Are you able to tell me if my question will be un-closed following my recent edits? Please bear in mind that the way I initially posted it was a complete beginner's error and I feel that, if the question now meets the criteria, it is unfair to have it still closed. Any help or further advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Your question is on its way to being reopened. I just cast the 4th vote to reopen, out of a possible 5. It just needs one more person to vote and then it will be open again.

Thank you very much @Rand al'Thor - much appreciated. I confess to being a little bewildered by this dark art but I am a keen learner. All good wishes.

The first hint was extremely helpful here. Searching Cornwall and railroad pioneer gave me the first few answers and from that point on it was mainly following the leads using a map and a search engine. That gave me this

 1. Tregajorran
 2. Richard Trevithick
 3. Dartford
 4. Carn Brea
 5. Ford Anglia from Harry Potter
 6. Redruth
 7. David Annand (assuming you want the sculptor of the Miner statue)
 8. Regal Cinema

